# lower bound on the size of a hitting set

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Let $\Lambda$ be the set of $n$-variate polynomials of total degree at most $d$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

We say that $H\subseteq\mathbb{F}^n_q$ is a $hitting\ set$ for $\Lambda$ if for every nonzero polynomial $f\in\Lambda$ there exists $x\in H$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$.

Prove that if $H$ is a hitting set for $\Lambda$ then $|H|\geq\binom{n+d}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\Lambda$ is a vector space and for $H=\{h_1,...,h_k\}$ so is $V=\mathbb{F}_q^k$. The set of $n$-variate monomials of degree at most $d$ is a basis for $\Lambda$, and this set has size $\tbinom{n+d}{n}$, so $\dim\Lambda = \tbinom{n+d}{n}$.

Define the linear map $\varphi:\Lambda \rightarrow V$ by $\varphi(p) = (p(h_1),...,p(h_k))$ and assume towards contradiction that $\dim V = |H| < \tbinom{n+d}{n}=\dim \Lambda$.

This implies that the map is not injective, and so it has a non-trivial kernel. Now observe that by the construction $p \in Ker\varphi$ implies that $p$ is a polynomial which vanishes on $H$.